# Does Y-cable USB double amperage?

Tags: usb, led-strip

We all know those Y-cables from an USB to SATA enclosure. They look like this:

[image]

If I spliced this up near the Mini B connector, so I have negative and positive, will I have doubled the amperage, if I hook up the two other ends to two identical USB wall chargers?

I am trying to power ~190 LEDs using USB, which works pretty well for all colors except white on a single 2.1A wall charger. I want to increase the amperage an easy way, without buying an expensive 5V 5A (or higher) power supply, but can this do the trick? If I grab two of the 2.1A wall chargers, I should be able to have ~4.2A, right?

Comment: I *think* you'd need to diode OR them and ensure your cable is capable of taking the current. Not sure I'd want to connect 5V outputs of PSUs directly together.  If that's the case, you're going to lose a bit across the diodes and get into messy cabling with in-line diodes.

Comment: @DiBosco I'm not sure if the cables can take the current, but they're well shielded, to an extent. I'm simply looking for a way to power these LED strips in a good, efficient way, without making the cost too high.

Comment: The cable might not be rated for that much current. Don't be surprised if you experience excessive heating and voltage droop.

Comment: Why "using USB"? What is the reason for this restriction? Normal USB ports are not designed for 2+ A of current, so combining two ports wouldn't give you the current you need, plus cables and connector contacts are not designed for that kind of current.

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that wall chargers are correctly isolated from mains (which I believe they are). 
You will double current although one of them will always work harder because of an output voltage unbalance (USB charger is a constant voltage source and there is always small difference between output voltage value). 
Once fully loaded they could go to constant current operation or more likely they will go to hiccup mode and automatic recovery. 
It's more secure to double voltage by connecting them in series and on that scenario adding diode across each output in reverse polarity.
Ideally... use correct supply.

Comment: But I don't need to double the voltage. If I decide to do this, is there really a big chance of failure, when we're only talking 5V at 4A?